# GnuCash delete backup and log files

Tags: logging, gnucash

Is it possible to auto delete gnucash backup and log files?

Maybe at least I can specify another location for such files?

**Edit** I've found a related issue in project's Bugzilla: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=601154

Answer (score 9):

If you want them to be removed automatically, Gnucash can remove them after a configurable amount of time (Preferences > General > "Days to retain log files").

Another chance would be to write a batch file to remove `.xac` and `.log` files inside the relevant directory.

You should notice that the backup and log files have a format of `<name>.YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.xac` (or `.log`). These are backup (and log) files from your data file, `<name>.`

Comment: What about removing them after Gnucash exit?

Comment: Call a script to open GnuCash.  Then have the script sit there running, waiting for GnuCash to close.  Once it is closed, then delete the backup files.  Instead of opening GnuCash directly, you open the script.  (adjust the shortcuts)